# How do I pass the current working directory to a command run from .tmux.conf?

Tags: tmux

I want my tmux status-line to display some info about the current git repository if the current working directory is in a git repository. I wrote a script which prints this info when given the current working directory. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to pass the current directory to the script! I have tried adding all of the following, and more to my .tmux.conf:

1.

```
set-window-option -g status-right "#(/Users/devon/scripts/git_check.py $PWD)"
```

2.

```
set-window-option -g status-right "#(/Users/devon/scripts/git_check.py #{pane_current_path)"
```

3. (after modifying my script to take its input from the `$TMUX_PATH` environment variable)

```
setenv -g TMUX_PATH = "$PWD"
set-window-option -g status-right "#(/Users/devon/scripts/git_check.py)"
```

I even tried setting `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to `'export TMUX_PATH=$PWD'` in  `.profile`, but it was all for naught. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a (sort of hacky) way to do this. I inserted this into my .profile:

```
[[ -n $TMUX ]] && PROMPT_COMMAND='tmux setenv -g TMUX_PATH "$PWD";tmux refresh-client -S;'
```

This sets tmux's `TMUX_PATH` environmental variable to the current path whenever a new bash prompt comes up. I can then read the environmental variable from the script. (This command also refreshes the status line--remove the `tmux refresh-client -s;` part to disable that.)

I'm pretty sure the issue was that tmux was running my script from within the shell from which it was loaded, meaning that the environmental variables from within my tmux session were not readable from my script. So I needed to export the local environmental variable to the shell outside of tmux, which I could then use in my script to get the current path within tmux.

Answer (score 0):

In `#(cd ..; pwd) #(pwd)` the cd only changes the pwd for the first command.

Answer (score 0):

```
# vim ~/.tmux.conf

# Get current working directory for outside program: use $TMUX_WORKING_DIR to get the active dir path of tmux
set-hook -g pane-focus-in 'if [ -z ${TMUX+x} ]; then eval "export $(tmux show-environment TMUX_WORKING_DIR)"; else tmux setenv TMUX_WORKING_DIR $(pwd); fi'
```

```
# vim ~/.bashrc

if [ -z ${TMUX+x} ]; then eval "export $(tmux show-environment TMUX_WORKING_DIR)" && cd $TMUX_WORKING_DIR; else tmux setenv TMUX_WORKING_DIR $(pwd); fi
clear
```

> https://yingshaoxo.blogspot.com/2021/05/how-to-enhance-ability-of-tmux.html